# How do I increase the amount of shrink size for a partition?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 298 GB HDD and it shows that I have 179 GB free. When I try to shrink my C drive, it will only allow me to shrink 9474 Mb. How do I increase this number? I have already defrag the drive.

Comment: With **Disk Management** you can only shrink a maximum of half of your partition size. A 3rd party tool is required to shrink more than that.

Comment: @RsyaStudios In disk management, when I try to shrink the volume, it will only allow 9474 Mb, thats not even close to half of my free space. It says, "Size of available shrink space in MB: 9474"

Comment: That means that some system files are installed up to there. The max half of partition size is after installing Windows. Over time 'immovable' files slowly get allocated around the partition.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is some system file Windows is currently using so you can't shrink to move the file (like Page file), to resize the partition, Windows PE or some [Third-party software is needed](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), besides, it is highly recommended you to backup existing data before re-sizing, partition corruption may happen (even a small chance of)